# Pyspark reads csv - NameError: name 'spark' is not defined

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to run the following code in databricks in order to call a spark session and use it to open a csv file:

```
spark
fireServiceCallsDF = spark.read.csv('/mnt/sf_open_data/fire_dept_calls_for_service/Fire_Department_Calls_for_Service.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

And I get the following error:

```
NameError:name 'spark' is not defined
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

I have also tried to run:

```
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

But got the following in response:

```
ImportError: cannot import name SparkSession
```

If it helps, I am trying to follow the following example (you will understand better if you watch it from from 17:30 on):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K14plpZgy_c&list=PLIxzgeMkSrQ-2Uizm4l0HjNSSy2NxgqjX

Comment: in case: [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sparksession)

Comment: I am using a databricks notebook. I am following this example (if you skip it untill 17:00 it's easier to understand):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K14plpZgy_c&list=PLIxzgeMkSrQ-2Uizm4l0HjNSSy2NxgqjX

Comment: I am not even able to import it through the following code:

    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

As I get the following:

    ImportError: cannot import name SparkSession

Answer (score 1):

I got it worked by using the following imports:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf                                                                                                                 
from pyspark.context import SparkContext                                                                                                      
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
```

I got the idea by looking into the pyspark code as I found read csv was working in the interactive shell.

Answer (score -2):

Please note the example code your are using is for Spark version 2.x

"spark" and "SparkSession" are not available on Spark 1.x. The error messages you are getting point to a possible version issue (Spark 1.x).

Check the Spark version you are using.

Comment: I am using Spark 2.0.

Comment: this is not a answer